# jquery appearing nav from the left

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown, slideup, right-to-left

I'm working on an website where I want an navigation that is coming from the left when the cursor is hovering to the left.

I found 1 link that looks very close to what I want but every time I try it for myself it doesn't work! I tried everything I know and looked closely if I copied every line on the page.

This is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/PktxV/

And this is the code:

HTML

```
<div id="sidePanel">
<div id="panelContent">
    <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FWebsTutorial&amp;width=200&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=253401284678598"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:258px;"
    allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="panelHandle">
    <p>Facebook</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    /* ===== Primary Styles ========================================================
   Author: NTechi | WebsTutorial
   ========================================================================== */
 body {
    font-family:Arial;
}
#sidePanel {
    width:245px;
    position:fixed;
    left:-202px;
    top:15%;
}
#panelHandle {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #222);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image:linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    height:150px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#panelContent {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
#panelHandle p {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -4px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
}
```

jQuery

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#panelHandle').hover(function () {
            $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
                'left': '0px'
            }, 900);
        }, function () {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        });

        jQuery('#sidePanel').hover(function () {
            // Do nothing
        }, function () {

            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({
                left: '-201px'
            }, 800);

        });
    });
});
```

Does anyone know if this is an older version or something or that it has trouble with an HTML5 page (what I'm trying to make) and maybe can get me a link of an newer/beter slider?

EDIT!!

This is how i have it in an HTML5 document

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* ===== Primary Styles ========================================================
   Author: NTechi | WebsTutorial
   ========================================================================== */
 body {
    font-family:Arial;
}
#sidePanel {
    width:245px;
    position:fixed;
    left:-202px;
    top:15%;
}
#panelHandle {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #222);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image:linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    height:150px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#panelContent {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
#panelHandle p {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -4px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<script src="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidePanel').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '-202px'
        }, 900);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="sidePanel">
    <div id="panelContent">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FWebsTutorial&amp;width=200&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=253401284678598"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:258px;"
        allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="panelHandle">
        <p>Facebook</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PktxV/3/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidePanel').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '-202px'
        }, 900);
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Change all of your page with HTML to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* ===== Primary Styles ========================================================
   Author: NTechi | WebsTutorial
   ========================================================================== */
 body {
    font-family:Arial;
}
#sidePanel {
    width:245px;
    position:fixed;
    left:-202px;
    top:15%;
}
#panelHandle {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333, #222);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    background-image:linear-gradient(center top, #333333, #222222);
    height:150px;
    width:40px;
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#panelContent {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #333333;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
}
#panelHandle p {
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -4px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
}
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidePanel').hover(function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '-202px'
        }, 900);
    });
});

</script>

</head>


<body>
<div id="sidePanel">
    <div id="panelContent">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FWebsTutorial&amp;width=200&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=253401284678598"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:258px;"
        allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="panelHandle">
        <p>Facebook</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: still the same. i see the facebook tab but when i move my cursor over it it doesnt slide to the right.

i also have the feeling that i'm just doing it wrong...

Comment: i have put some extra info to show how i'v put it in an HTML5 doc

Comment: @RonPelt so you don't want to slide to the left after the mouse leaves the DIV? It slides to the right and then stays "open"?

Comment: i want it how it is. sorry if i'm a little bit confusing but english is not my first language.

the only change i want is that its showing with just 1 line of text and if you click on it you will go to the next page like any other navigation. The problem is that it somehow doesnt work on my website.

Comment: @RonPelt what line of text are you talking about? What is the next page that should load when you click on that line?

Comment: how to explain this.... try picturing an page with half a div to the side and once you move over there with your cursor it shows the entire div with in it one line of text (for example "home" "contact" "forum") and when you move away the div returns to the left and in its original position.

Comment: @RonPelt your page does not have a navigation bar. It only has a Facebook Tab on the left. To aplly that slide effect you first need to create the navigation bar. Edit your question so it shows everything we need to help you.

Comment: thats what i'm trying to explain. If this effect works than i'm going to edit it to an navigation bar but it first has to work to do so. the only problem i have and need to solve is why the effect itself doesnt work when i put it in my website.

Comment: @RonPelt I tried on my local machine, made some changes and it works. See my responde again and replace all of your HTML. Test it please.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not including the jQuery library and therefore the JavaScript is not running.

What errors are you seeing on your page?  Check your JavaScript console.

Comment: thats just it. there are no errors at all. i even tried an alert but it doesnt show.

Comment: i have put some extra info to show how i'v put it in an HTML5 doc